# Tensorflow, iterate tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I defined my loss function and I want to iterative each item of the batch to calculate the loss function. I used `tf.map_fn` however, I found it is very slow. Are there any suggestions?

```py
def loss(phi, mu, sigma, t_phi, t_mu, t_sigma):
    _loss = 0.0
    for i in range(phi.shape[0]):
        for j in range(phi.shape[0]):
            _loss += phi[i] * phi[j] * pdf(mu[i], mu[j], tf.sqrt(sigma[i]**2 + sigma[j]**2))
            _loss += t_phi[i] * t_phi[j] * pdf(t_mu[i], t_mu[j], tf.sqrt(t_sigma[i]**2 + t_sigma[j]**2))
            _loss += -2 * phi[i] * t_phi[j] * pdf(mu[i], t_mu[j], tf.sqrt(sigma[i]**2 + t_sigma[j]**2))
    return tf.sqrt(_loss)

def reduce_loss(phi, mu, sigma, t_phi, t_mu, t_sigma):
    with tf.variable_scope('loss') as loss:
        stacked = tf.stack([phi, mu, sigma, t_phi, t_mu, t_sigma], 1)
        return tf.map_fn(lambda x: loss(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]), stacked,
                         parallel_iterations=4)

def pdf(x, mu, sigma):
    return tf.exp(-0.5*(x-mu)**2/sigma**2) / ((2*np.pi*sigma**2)**0.5)
```

The batch size is 1024.

Comment: `pdf` is pdf of multivariate Gaussian ? Also can you show the code of `pdf`

Comment: @mujjiga I added it in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can eliminate the loops in your `loss` function. This is done by vectorising everything. For example you iterate through `i` and `j` to calculate `phi[i]*phi[j]` But this is the ij'th element of `tf.matmul(phi[:, None], phi[None, :])`. Doing this should be faster than the implementation with loops.

Also, because tensorflow builds the graph statically, your function could take a loooong time to even build the graph. You should generally avoid big nested for loops in tensorflow for this reason.

I have made an example with part of your loss function vectorised, it should be easy to do the other parts.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from numpy import pi as PI
from time import time


# some random vectors
size = 10
phi = tf.random.uniform([size])
mu = tf.random.uniform([size])
sigma = tf.random.uniform([size])


####################################
# Your original loss
####################################

def pdf(x, m, s):
    return tf.exp(-0.5*(x-m)**2/s**2) / ((2*PI*s**2)**0.5)


def loss():
    _loss = 0.0
    for i in range(phi.shape[0]):
        for j in range(phi.shape[0]):
            _loss += phi[i] * phi[j] * pdf(mu[i], mu[j], tf.sqrt(sigma[i]**2 + sigma[j]**2))
    return tf.sqrt(_loss)


####################################
# vectorised loss
####################################

def vector_pdf(x, s):
    return tf.exp(-0.5*x**2/s**2) / ((2*PI*s**2)**0.5)


def vectorised_loss():
    phi_ij = tf.matmul(phi[:, None], phi[None, :])
    difference = mu[:, None] - mu[None, :]
    sigma_squared = sigma**2
    sigma_sum = tf.sqrt(sigma_squared[:, None] + sigma_squared[None, :])

    loss_array = phi_ij*vector_pdf(difference, sigma_sum)
    return tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(loss_array))


#######################################
# Time the functions and show they are the same
#######################################

with tf.Session() as sess:
    loop_loss = loss()
    vector_loss = vectorised_loss()
    # init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    # sess.run(init)

    t = 0.
    for _ in range(100):
        st = time()
        loop_loss_val = sess.run(loop_loss)
        t += time() - st
    print('loop took {}'.format(t/100))

    t = 0.
    for _ in range(100):
        st = time()
        vector_val = sess.run(vector_loss)
        t += time() - st
    print('vector took {}'.format(t / 100))

    l_val, v_val = sess.run([loop_loss, vector_loss])
    print(l_val, v_val)
```

This prints

```
loop took 0.01740453243255615
vector took 0.004280190467834472
4.6466274 4.6466274
```

By vectorising the loss function, your reduce function should be straightforward to vectorise as well. Now you will want to batch matmul, and slightly change the indices of the subtractions. For example:

```
mu[:, None] - mu[None, :]
# becomes
mu[: ,:, None] - mu[:, None, :]
```